# running elf on (qemu emulated) ppc failed - strace error

Tags: elf, qemu, strace, powerpc

I would like to execute an elf executable, which was compiled for ppc32.
I am using QEMU to emulate ppc architecture.

When I use strace to check if there are some library files or dependencies needed I get an error at the beginning.

strace on the existing running machine:

```
strace ./program
execve("./program", ["./program"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
```

strace on the QEMU machine:

```
strace ./program
execve("./program", ["./program"], [/* 16 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

How is it possible to know which files are missing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an `ENOENT` during `execve`, it's likely due to one of two things:

1. the binary itself is missing; or
2. the dynamic linker requested by the binary is missing.

I'm going to assume that you've checked for (1), in which case it's probably the dynamic linker.

You can check which linker the program is requesting with `readelf --program-headers`:

```
[jk@pudge bin]$ readelf --program-headers ./program 

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x10000ae4
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 64
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000010000040 0x0000000010000040
                 0x00000000000001c0 0x00000000000001c0  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000200 0x0000000010000200 0x0000000010000200
                 0x0000000000000011 0x0000000000000011  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000010000000 0x0000000010000000
                 0x000000000000133c 0x000000000000133c  R E    10000
  LOAD           0x000000000000fd28 0x000000001001fd28 0x000000001001fd28
                 0x0000000000000388 0x0000000000000398  RW     10000
  DYNAMIC        0x000000000000fd50 0x000000001001fd50 0x000000001001fd50
                 0x00000000000001b0 0x00000000000001b0  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000214 0x0000000010000214 0x0000000010000214
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000000000000fd28 0x000000001001fd28 0x000000001001fd28
                 0x00000000000002d8 0x00000000000002d8  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame 
   03     .ctors .dtors .jcr .dynamic .got .plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     
   07     .ctors .dtors .jcr .dynamic .got
```

[See the `Requesting program interpreter` line from the `INTERP` header].

Once you know this, you'll need to actually provide that dynamic linker. The `-L` flag to qemu can be useful to tell qemu where to search for the linker. Typically, you'd point `-L` to a sysroot for the emulated architecture.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer!
If I execute the command on my original machine I get this answer
[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld.so.1]
if I do the same on the qemu machine I get this:
[Requesting program interpreter: ib/ld.so.1]

This don't make any sense to me? 

Do you mean, I have to add the dynamic linker when I execute qemu, or is it possible to define the dynamic linker when I try to execute the elf file?

Comment: Update: It seems that there was a problem with the binary. I downloaded the file via tftp, I have tried several times via tftp, but it seems that there was a problem with that. After I downloaded it via ftp, it works. 
It is a very big elf file, which much dependencies, is there a way, to get an image of a working powerpc machine and run it in the qemu? I think it would be a hard challange, to only try to run the "program" file on the emulated powerpc linux. If I start the elf now, it exits after a few seconds.